# On back button shows same activity over and over

Tags: android, android-activity

I have activity A which can open Activity B. The problem that I am having is, if I open Activity B and then close Activity B and re open Activity B, when i pressed the back button I will see Activity B again. It seems every time I open the activity the activity gets added on the stack and not being destroyed when using finish() or onBackPressed(). Any help would be appreciated!

This is how I open my activity B from Activity A:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setClass(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Activity B back button is called using:

```
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            onBackPressed();
            //finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Manifest XML:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.FirstActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        </activity>

      <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.ActivityA"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.project.ActivityB"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
```

Comment: post your manifest xml

Comment: @AcauãPitta thank you for your reply I updated with my XML, I unfortunately, im not able to add my full XML so I copied the activity values and changed the names.

Comment: Makes no sense. Please add debug logging in `onDestroy()` and `onCreate()` of `ActivityB`. Then run your app and see what is happening.

Comment: @DavidWasser Thank you for your response. I removed the meta-data solution and added logs, is there a specific log I should be adding? right now it just print on create and on destroy respectively and I see both.

Comment: OK, so you can now see when an `Activity` is being created and destroyed. In `ActivityA` you should log "ActivityA in onCreate()" and in `ActivityB` you should log "ActivityB in onCreate()", etc. Now run it and you can see when each `Activity` is being created and destroyed. Then tell us what is happening.

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you! I see Activity A being created, then AcitivtyB gets created, then destroyed, and ActivityA on Resume

Comment: ok. So this all sounds correct. What isn't working as you want it (or as expected)? Please explain the scenario that doesn't work and what the logs say in that case.

Comment: @DavidWasser thank you for your help! it was a strange issue, whenever I would go to Activity B and then went back it would keep ActivityB on the stack, so if I were to go back to activity B from the Activity A and then press the back button, it would stay on activity B until I pressed back the same amount of time I opened activity B. Activity B is oped though a button on Activity A. Weirdly, after implementing the fix below the problem went away. I did not do any other code changes. I removed it as well and it still worked. It could have been my device and emulator.

Comment: Well, as I said, the change to add the meta-data can't possibly have fixed your problem. So it must have been something else you did. Please create an answer and write what you think happened, or just delete this question. Otherwise, this incorrect accepted answer is likely to confuse others.

Comment: Thank you @DavidWasser unfortunately i am unable to delete the question for some reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in mainfest.xml  >> add

```
<activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ActivityA" />
```

`

Comment: thank you for your help! This did that trick! Can you explain to me why we need to do this?

Comment: No. This can't actually help. This is a coincidence.